# Banner moving left and right when i zoom in and out

Tags: html, css, ads, banner

when i zoom out it moves left, when i zoom in, it moves right
here is my code:

```
.google {
position:absolute;
display:block;
right:200px;
width:728px;
top:90px;
border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

how do i fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Post your actual website or a demo. This CSS isn't very helpful.

Comment: That's just some CSS which doesn't tell us much.  Post a relevant reproducible example with HTML.  Please read the FAQ:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Zomming in as in "Cmd+" or as in resizing the browser window so that its' smaller?

Answer (score 0):

Hey now give to **body** `min-width` as like this

```
body{
min-width:1000px;
}
```

---

and i saw you layout i found some error add to this css in your style sheet and remove the some error of search form

**if you required**

```
.onethousand_wrap {
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
}
```